# LLDB equivalent of `po` in GDB in Xcode4.1?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, debugging, gdb, lldb

There is a command `po` in GDB which prints Objective-C object details. (with its description)
In LLDB, `po` just print memory address. How can I see similar output of GDB in LLDB?

Comment: consider deleting this question since LLDB does have po

Comment: @VincentGable No. Because of same reason why we're using SCM.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is implemented nowadays. For completeness sake, it is an alias to this command:

```
expression -o  --
```

For help with this and other LLDB commands, use the command help:

```
help expression
```

Comment: That's what I thought from the docs.  However, whenever I try that I get the following output:  error: instance method 'userData' has incompatible result types in different translation units ('void *' vs. 'id')
note: instance method 'userData' also declared here
note: declared here with type 'id'
error: 1 errors parsing expression

Comment: Well to me that looks more like an error in the code than a problem in LLDB.

Answer (score 4):

Here are some handy [GDB to LLDB command equivalents](http://lldb.llvm.org/lldb-gdb.html).

Answer (score 3):

It looks like not implemented yet at this time. http://lldb.llvm.org/status.html

Comment: What isn't there yet:

Regression test suite
Operating system support hasn't been fully modularized yet
Blocks support
Calling functions in expressions
Objective-C 2.0 Support: Printing properties, synthetic properties, Objective-C expressions, KVO, dynamic types, dot syntax, runtime data
C++ support: Method access, handling demangled names, dynamic types
Exception support: Breaking by name, thrown object, thrower

Answer (score 1):

Don't know lldb, but maybe something to the effect of:

```
print _NSPrintForDebugger(obj)
```